# Yup validate array of enums in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, enums, yup

I am trying to validate DTO's using Yup and i can't resolve an issue with checking enums. I have a code similar to the one below:

```
export enum TestEnum {
  TEST = 0,
  NOT_TEST = 1,
}

export interface SampleDTO {
  testEnum: TestEnum[];
}

export const sampleDtoSchema: SchemaOf<SampleDTO> = yup.object({
  testEnum: yup
    .array(
      yup
        .mixed<TestEnum>()
        .oneOf(Object.values(TestEnum) as TestEnum[])
        .required(),
    )
    .ensure(),
});
```

And i get this error:

```
Type 'MixedSchema<TestEnum | undefined, AnyObject, TestEnum>' is not assignable to type 'BaseSchema<Maybe<TestEnum.NOT_TEST>, AnyObject, TestEnum.NOT_TEST>'.
          Types of property '__inputType' are incompatible.
            Type 'TestEnum | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Maybe<TestEnum.NOT_TEST>'.
              Type 'TestEnum.TEST' is not assignable to type 'Maybe<TestEnum.NOT_TEST>'
```

How it should be done correctly?

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful:

```
export const sampleDtoSchema: yup.SchemaOf<SampleDTO> = yup.object({
  testEnum: yup
    .array(
      yup
        .mixed()
        .oneOf<TestEnum>(Object.values(TestEnum) as TestEnum[])
        .required()
    )
    .min(1)
    .ensure()
});
```